# how to do XML Parsing in Android Studio 1.4.1?

Tags: android

I am new to android working with  XML parsing. I written a XMLParser.java class where to parse the xml. But when I am trying it is not working with `DefaultHTTPClient` in android studio. can anyone please help me out how to use `Http URlConnection` for below code?

```
 public String getXmlFromUrl(String url)
  {

   String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can we see the error and stack trace as printed by your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
String xml=null;
// defaultHttpClient
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
URI uri = new URI(url);
httpPost.setURI(uri);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    .........
}
```

If not work, please post your logcat